# How do I make sure that the input is not null and that only one character is being entered?

Tags: java, regex, null, char, boolean

```
public static boolean correctchar(char b) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    b = scan.next().charAt(0);
    
    if (Character.toString(b).matches("^[a-zA-Z]") ) {
        System.out.println("True");
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("False");
        return false;
    }
}
```

I have this method that checks whether the input is a letter in the alphabet or not, but I want to make sure that the input from the user is not null and that the user only enters one letter. For example "`A`" or "`a`" is a correct char, the problem is if I enter "`Abcdef`" then it is still true as the first letter is still a valid char. I want to make it so that  the user can only enter one char, I think I've done that by using the scanner and `charAt(0)` but is there a more efficient way to do it, and I'm also not sure how to make it so that the input isn't null.

Comment: You can check length of string. String class has a length() method

Comment: But variable is originally a char so when I do that then it doesnt let me check the length.

Comment: @john Whay are you reading the input in `correctchar()` if you are passing `b` as a parameter to the method? You probably need to be reading the input at the calling site just before where you are calling `correctchar()` and then pass the read character to `correctchar()`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, do you mean in the main method?

Comment: @john Yes, that value will be accepted from the user in the main method(or anywhere where you are calling the method `correctchar()`) and the entered value will be passed while calling this method: `correctchar(enteredValue)`;

Answer (score 3):

I've revised your code to do what you wanted:

```
public static boolean correctchar(char b) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = scan.next();
    
    // This checks if the input is null, is empty (i.e., "") or is bigger than one character
    // If any of these conditions are fulfilled, then we return false.
    if (input == null || input.length() != 1) {
        return false;
    }

    b = input.charAt(0);
    
    if (Character.toString(b).matches("[a-zA-Z]") ) {
        System.out.println("True");
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("False");
        return false;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Without scanner (see comments):

```
public static boolean correctchar(char b, String input) {        
    // This checks if the input is null, is empty (i.e., "") or is bigger than one character
    // If any of these conditions are fulfilled, then we return false.
    if (input == null || input.length() != 1) {
        return false;
    }

    b = input.charAt(0);
    
    if (Character.toString(b).matches("[a-zA-Z]") ) {
        System.out.println("True");
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("False");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just updated your code for a few things: (1) Changed `input.length` to  `input.length()`. (2) You could simply write `input.length() != 1` instead of `input.isEmpty() || input.length > 1`. (3) You didn't need `^` before `[a-zA-Z]` though it was not causing any harm. In case of `matches`, `^` (i.e. start of line) and `$` (i.e. end of line) are redundant.

Comment: What if i didn't have the scanner and was passing it through the parameter?

Comment: Remove the scanner related lines and replace any mentions of 'input' with 'b'

Comment: I've also added a version in my answer as reference.

Comment: @user11350388 - Your edit is not correct. The question John has asked is what if `input` is passed as a parameter instead of getting it using a `Scanner`. You can simply roll back your edit to my last edit. Also, note that `b == null` is blatantly wrong as `b` is primitive and therefore you can not compare it with `null`.

Comment: Ok, I reverted the changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static boolean correctChar() {
     try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
         String input = null;
         do {
             input = scan.next();
             if (input != null && input.length() == 1) {
                 boolean isCorrect = input.matches("[a-zA-Z]"); 
                 System.out.println(isCorrect ? "True" : "False");
                 return isCorrect;
             } else {
                 System.out.println("Insert only one character");
             }
         } while (true);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I made couple of changes :

1. If invalid input ask user to enter again.
2. Make sure to close the scanner scan.close()

   ```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter only one character : ");

    String input = scan.next();

    while (null == input || input.isEmpty() || input.length() > 1) {
        System.out.println("Invaid Input, Please enter only one character : ");
        input = scan.next();
    }
    scan.close();

    if (Character.toString(input.charAt(0)).matches("^[a-zA-Z]")) {
        System.out.println("True");
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("False");
        return false;
    }
   ```

   }